# Differential equation scaling to unity

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems

In the article found here, http://journals.plos.org/plosone/article?id=10.1371/journal.pone.0010444#s5
there is a models as,
[image]
Then it says, "Without loss of generality we can scale the maximum level of innate immunity, j to unity ".
I am trying to use similar sort of approach to my model, but there are few things that I don't understand and I would appreciate if someone can clarify these to me.

1. What is the meaning of scaling it to unity and how is it done? (Say, it is known that $j=10^{10}$).
2. In the absence of bacteria, wouldn't these inactivated bacteria keep on exponentially decreasing at rate d?
3. If it is assumed that the innate immune system gets activated only under the presence of bacteria, when the bacteria is not in the system, how can the activated immune system be set to be at a level 0?

Comment: Can you phrase this question such that no knowledge of the underlying biology is required for answering?